# How to load a specific component when we click on a Card which takes us to an external page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a card item as follows : -

```
<CardItem
      src='images/img-9.jpg'
      text='Sentiment Analysis Using CNN'
      label='Deep Learning'
      path='/cnn-project' />
```

I have created a route as : -

```
<Route path='/cnn-project'  component={() => { window.open("https://www.w3schools.com"); return null;}}/>
```

This is working fine .When I click on the card it takes me to the site link in new tab but the component in which I have the card changes and now just footer and the header is visible .Lets say we have card in Project component .

What I want is that after clicking the card it takes me to the site in new tab while Project component is still being displayed in my localhost 3000 ,while currently after clicking it is showing just the footer and header .

How to do that ?

Comment: `window.open("https://www.w3schools.com", '_bank');` to open new tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `window.open` works, but simulaneously you're changing your app's path to `/cnn-project`, which doen't have any mapping since you return `null`..

Create a component you want displayed at `/cnn-project` route or simply go back to the previous path, like so:

```
const BrowserHistory = require('react-router/lib/BrowserHistory').default;

<Route path='/cnn-project'  component={() => { 
    window.open("https://www.w3schools.com"); 
    BrowserHistory.goBack();

    return null;}}/>
```

**edit**
Just switch the `Route` prop from `component` to `render` and move this `window.open` to your new component's `componentDidMount`.

```
<Route path='/cnn-project' render={() => <MyNewComponent />} />
```

```
class MyNewComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        window.open("https://www.w3schools.com");
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error although I have installed  using rpm install history ... Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router/lib/BrowserHistory'

Comment: How to Create a component I  want display at /cnn-project route as I am aready created a route for that which opens  the new tab